# Executing a function in Python

Tags: python

I am having a spot of bother with the following script, it uses a function within it:

```
def my_function(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    print("I love listening to %s" %(arg1))
    print("It is normally played at %d BPM" %(arg2))
    print("I also like listening to %s" %(arg3))
    print("Dat be da bomb playa!")

print("What music do you like listening to?")
ans1 = input(">>")

print("What speed is that usually played at?")
ans2 = input(">>")

print("whats your second favourite genre of music?")
ans3 = input(">>")

my_function(ans1, ans2, ans3)
```

I get to the first user input: What music do you like listening to? When I type in 'House' and hit enter, I am expecting the second question to be displayed, but I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "ex19_MyFunction.py", line 26, in <module> ans1 = input(">>") 
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'house' is not defined**
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Python2 then use `raw_input()` because `input()` try to parse text as python code and you get error.

Comment: Thanks furas. that did the trick.

Comment: However I have a second issue...it is related to the functions 2nd argument "print("It is normally played at %d BPM" %(arg2))'....when the user is asked: "print("What speed is that usually played at?")", the input is in 'int' format so I know why the error is coming up (I think), because %d is a string formatter....what would be the correct code to write so that the argument accepts an 'int' input from the user?

Comment: sorry dude - ignore me. I figured it out....I replaced %d with %s and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Your script would run just fine in Python3, so I am assuming you are using Python2. Change `input` to `raw_input`.

In Python2, `raw_input` will convert the input to a string, while `input('foo')` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input('foo'))`.